# ExpansionTile and SingleChildScrollView not working together in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I avoid the overflowing in my text when using `ExpansionTile` widget? When I was not using this widget my text was not overflowing and using `SingleChildScrollView` was enough.

```
ExpansionTile(
    title: Text('History'),
    children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child:Text(widget.descriptionText as String),
        ),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Can you include full widget and what are you expecting overflow

Answer (score 3):

A single child scroll view can take infinite height if not bound. You can try wrapping it with a `SizedBox` of a specific height:

```dart
ExpansionTile(
    title: Text('History'),
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 500,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child:Text(widget.descriptionText as String),
        ),
    )
    ]
)
```